# Opinions on kd tree for map nodes visualisation

Tags: java, neo4j, data-visualization, kdtree

I need you opinion on this. 
I have gps coordinates stored in a graph database and I need to visualize them on a map. If I try to place them all at once on the map the program will crash due to the large number of map points (2-3 million nodes). So I have to limit the number of nodes showing on the map at certain time. I need to group up and show less nodes when I view the whole map and as I zoom in on the map more and more nodes to appear in the specific area. My idea is to connect the nodes in the graph db into a KD tree so I can do a range search and display the nodes on the map for the current map location. The one thing that bugs me is how to show only part of the nodes on the map when its not zoomed so the app wont crash. 
Any suggestions or ideas on how to do this would be really appreciated.

Btw the graph db is neo4j, java api and for the maps i guess unfolding maps is one of the better solutions.

Thank you in advance